# AWS MWAA conflicting dependencies between compatible versions requirements.txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, airflow, dependency-management, mwaa

I am setting up a AWS Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) environment using `airflow` version `2.6.3`, and I am using a `requirements.txt` file to install my desired python packages as suggested by [Amazon's Development Guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#configuring-dag-dependencies-upload). However, `pip` is not able to install the requested dependencies because, apparently, there are conflicts.

My `requirements.txt` file is the following:

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.3/constraints-3.10.txt"
awswrangler~=3.4.0
```

The error logs in CloudWatch show the following errors:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r /usr/local/airflow/requirements/requirements.txt because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
awswrangler 3.4.2 depends on numpy<2.0 and >=1.18
awswrangler 3.4.1 depends on numpy<2.0 and >=1.18
awswrangler 3.4.0 depends on numpy<2.0 and >=1.18

The user requested (constraint) numpy==1.24.4
```

As we see, the package `awswrangler` requires `numpy` with version between `1.18` and `2.0`. The `constraints` specify `numpy==1.24.4`, which is clearly in the range, but `pip` fails anyway because of a dependency problem.

I've tried pinning `numpy` version in the `requirements.txt` file before `awswrangler`, but the error persists.

Any ideas how I could fix this problem? Does not look like a problem in my environment configuration.

Many thanks in advance.